# In Apache Spark how could I merge multiple SQL columns from an exploded JSON Array?

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading multiple JSON files from a directory; this JSON has multiple items 'cars' in an array. I'm trying to explode and merge the discrete values from the item 'car' to one dataframe.

A JSON file looks like:

```
{
    "cars": {
        "items": 
            [
                {

                    "latitude": 42.0001,
                    "longitude": 19.0001,
                    "name": "Alex"
                },
                {

                    "latitude": 42.0002,
                    "longitude": 19.0002,
                    "name": "Berta"
                },
                {

                    "latitude": 42.0003,
                    "longitude": 19.0003,
                    "name": "Chris"
                },
                {

                    "latitude": 42.0004,
                    "longitude": 19.0004,
                    "name": "Diana"
                }
            ]
    }
}
```

My approaches to explode and merge the values to just one dataframe are:

```
// Read JSON files
val jsonData = sqlContext.read.json(s"/mnt/$MountName/.")
// To sqlContext to DataFrame
val jsonDF = jsonData.toDF()

/* Approach 1 */
// User-defined function to 'zip' two columns
val zip = udf((xs: Seq[Double], ys: Seq[Double]) => xs.zip(ys))
jsonDF.withColumn("vars", explode(zip($"cars.items.latitude", $"cars.items.longitude"))).select($"cars.items.name", $"vars._1".alias("varA"), $"vars._2".alias("varB"))

/* Apporach 2 */
val df = jsonData.select($"cars.items.name", $"cars.items.latitude", $"cars.items.longitude").toDF("name", "latitude", "longitude")
val df1 = df.select(explode(df("name")).alias("name"), df("latitude"), df("longitude"))
val df2 = df1.select(df1("name").alias("name"), explode(df1("latitude")).alias("latitude"), df1("longitude"))
val df3 = df2.select(df2("name"), df2("latitude"), explode(df2("longitude")).alias("longitude"))
```

As you may see the result of the **Approach 1** is just a dataframe of two discrete 'merged' parameters like:

```
+--------------------+---------+---------+
|                name|     varA|     varB|
+--------------------+---------+---------+
|[Leo, Britta, Gor...|48.161079|11.556778|
|[Leo, Britta, Gor...|48.124666|11.617682|
|[Leo, Britta, Gor...|48.352043|11.788091|
|[Leo, Britta, Gor...| 48.25184|11.636337|
```

The result for Approach is as follows:

```
+----+---------+---------+
|name| latitude|longitude|
+----+---------+---------+
| Leo|48.161079|11.556778|
| Leo|48.161079|11.617682|
| Leo|48.161079|11.788091|
| Leo|48.161079|11.636337|
| Leo|48.161079|11.560595|
| Leo|48.161079|11.788632|
```

(The result is a mapping of each 'name' with each 'latitude' with each 'longitude')

The result should be as follows:

```
+--------------------+---------+---------+
|                name|     varA|     varB|
+--------------------+---------+---------+
|Leo                 |48.161079|11.556778|
|Britta              |48.124666|11.617682|
|Gorch               |48.352043|11.788091|
```

Do you know how read the files, split and merge the values that each line is just one object?

Thanks you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For getting the expected result you can try following approach:

```
// Read JSON files
val jsonData = sqlContext.read.json(s"/mnt/$MountName/.")
// To sqlContext to DataFrame
val jsonDF = jsonData.toDF()

// Approach
val df1 = jsonDF.select(explode(df("cars.items")).alias("items"))
val df2 = df1.select("items.name", "items.latitude", "items.longitude")
```

The above approach will provide you following result:

```
+-----+--------+---------+
| name|latitude|longitude|
+-----+--------+---------+
| Alex| 42.0001|  19.0001|
|Berta| 42.0002|  19.0002|
|Chris| 42.0003|  19.0003|
|Diana| 42.0004|  19.0004|
+-----+--------+---------+
```